# Connecting to a Remote Symfony Database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses

Tags: php, database, symfony, ionos

I recently attempted to deploy my Symfony application to a server hosted with Ionos. I've configured the database parameters in both the .env file and the doctrine.yaml file, but I'm encountering an error when trying to connect to the database.

Here are the details of my configuration:

**.env:**

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://dbu53*****:password@db50146*****.hosting-data.io:3306/dbs121*****"
```

**doctrine.yaml File:**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '8.0'
        charset: utf8mb4
        host: 'db50146*****.hosting-data.io'
        port: 3306
        user: 'dbu53*****'
        password: 'password'
        dbname: 'dbs121*****'
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

However, when I attempt to connect to the database, I get the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Unknown host.`

I suspect that the issue may be related to how I've configured the database connection parameters, but I'm not sure about the source of this error. Are there any obvious errors in my configuration? Is there something specific I should check?

I appreciate any help that can be provided in resolving this issue with Symfony's remote database connection.

Comment: Im not sure if this is still the case but in earlier versions you had to encode your password / user if it contained special characters. Maybe one field does so?

Answer (score 0):

That error implies that your host was not resolved by the dns. Sometimes that's because your username or password contains a `@` sign, which need to be escaped first. It could be in some cases the `'` and `"` also need to be escaped.

If you use a doctrine url, you don't have to specify all the other properties like `driver`, `server_version`, `charset`, `host`, `port`, `user`, `password` and `dbname`. These can all be derived from the url. Not all environments are the same, so you can configure these in one url.

Example:

```
[driver]://[user]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[dbname]?charset=[charset]&server_version=[server_version]

mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/my_db?chartset=utf8_mb4&server_version=8.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestions. I've followed your advice, including the example you provided for structuring the database connection URL.

However, the issue ```SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Unknown host``` persists despite that. I've verified various aspects, including the connection information, firewalls, and permission rules, but I haven't resolved the problem yet.

If you have any other ideas or suggestions to address this issue, I'm open to any further assistance you can provide.

Comment: I've been looking elsewhere, but I see there are lots of people asking the same question about resources on hosting-data.io. Are you sure that subdomain is present in dns? I can't verify it, because you've anonymised it.